# Android animation not working with View Binding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, animation

So I was trying animation on Android using [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and it was not working, I tried the old way of getting views (findViewById()) and it happened to work just fine. Any answer to why View Binding doesn't work with animations? Thanks in advance for any answer.
Here the example code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sopint_background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bordered"
    android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="12sp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="I am a text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

logo_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-50%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="1500"
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

and MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

//Binding
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

//Variables
lateinit var topAnimation: Animation
lateinit var logo: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
    logo = findViewById(R.id.tvLogo)
    topAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(applicationContext, R.anim.logo_animation)
    logo.startAnimation(topAnimation)

    //This does not work
    //binding.tvLogo.startAnimation((topAnimation))

}
```

}

Comment: is this a typo or you haven't removed `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` when using bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

What you're doing here is

- inflating a layout, storing it in `binding`
- displaying that inflated layout
- replacing that and displaying *another* inflated copy of the layout

`binding.tvLogo.startAnimation((topAnimation))`

This doesn't work because you can't see it happening - you're animating the `View` on the *first* layout you inflated, but it's the *second* one that's being displayed, and you're not interacting with that.

```
logo = findViewById(R.id.tvLogo)
logo.startAnimation(topAnimation)
```

Whereas this one works because you're looking up `tvLogo` on the *currently displayed* layout (the second one) and then animating *that* `View`. Because it's the one on the screen, you see the results

---

Basically, if you ever find yourself inflating a layout more than once, that's a sign you're doing something wrong (there can be situations where you would, but in that case you'd know why you're doing it!). And the same goes for multiple `setContentView` calls

Comment: Thanks @cactustictacs for the detailed explanation, I somehow didn't see that. I'll be more careful now on wards (feeling silly)

Comment: @RoyRichardFloresGonzalez it actually comes up a lot on here, so don't feel bad! We've all done it at some point, it's just something to look for if things don't seem to be working